# Can we restrict particular string case while loading it to Arraylist object?

Tags: java, string, generics, bounded-wildcard, bounded-types

A file consisting of many words, where some words are purely in 'UPPERCASE', some words are purely in 'lowercase' and rest are in 'miXeDCasE'?
I want to load these words to Arraylist object but it should not allow to load words in UPPERCASE.

Can we achieve this with Java Generics ? How ?

For Ex: as we can achieve only number can be inserted in below Arraylist object with help of bounded types concept of Java Generics.

```
> ArrayList <T extends Number> al = new ArrayList<T extends Number>();
```

Comment: Not with generics but with java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't thing generics provide such functionality for your requirement but you can achieve this easily with following logic if using generics is not mandatory for you

```
String word = "SomeWordFromYourFile";
String wordToUpperCase = word.toUpperCase();
if(!wordToUpperCase.equals(word)) {
     list.add(word);
}
```

Comment: This is ABSOLUTELY NOT the op ask for.

Comment: Yes I know it. But as you may know that java generics does not provide facility requested by user so I have posted one possible answer. If your having better answer then post it, I will be happy to upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Generics is a NO. But regular expressions are the best tools to handle this type of scenarios.

**Demo:**
Consider a `String` array that holds words. Later in your code, you can replace this array with the file contents that you read in.

```
String[] words = { "UPPER", "lower", "LowER", "don", "shawn", "DUDE", "BAGGAGE", "buddy", "FrIeNd", "NeRd",
                "geek", "FREAK" };
```

Now, let's filter this array and skip the uppercase words and add the rest to an `ArrayList`

```
List<String> filteredWords = new ArrayList<>();
for(String eachWord : words){
          //Matches one or more occurrence
            if(!eachWord.matches("[A-Z]+")){
                filteredWords.add(eachWord);
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }
//Print the resulting array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filteredWords.toArray()));
```

And the generated output will be:

> [lower, LowER, don, shawn, buddy, FrIeNd, NeRd, geek]

I hope this is what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @Aubin, you are right. * matches zero or more occurrences where as + matches at least one or more and in this case, + would suite more. Thanks for pointing out. I've edited my post accordingly.